# how to crawl .xml.gz using sitemaps spider

Tags: python-2.7, sitemap, scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name="sitemap"
    sitemap_urls = ['https://play.google.com/sitemaps/sitemaps-index-0.xml']

```
sitemap_rules =[
    ('/app/', 'parse_product'),
    ]               
def parse(self, response):

     yield  scrapy.Request(response.url,callback=self.parse_product)



def parse_product(self, response):

       yield {

          'applicationName' : (response.css('div.id-app-title ::text').extract_first()).encode("utf-8") ,
          'publishedBy' : (response.css('div a.document-subtitle.primary span::text').extract_first()).encode("utf-8") ,

           }
```